# java.awt.robot is not capturing screen in mac os x ventura

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am trying to capture screen in mac os ventura using java.awt.robort but it captures the desktop image every time but not the image of current application running. As shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/KABpT.png. Also it does not captures the second screen attached to laptop.

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            for (GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
                screenRect =    screenRect.union(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
            }
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = new   Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);

            /*
             * final BufferedImage screenFullImage = new Robot() .createScreenCapture(new
             * Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
             */
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, AppConstants.JPG_FORMAT, new     File(imageFilePath.toString()));
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it clear now?